# windows 7 compatibility windows registry windows xp issue

Tags: windows-7, registry, compatibility

I have an application developed in VC++ 2010 , it runs in xp , it also runs in Windows 7 when i check the run in XP mode. When i check the run in xp mode , it sets a string value in HK_LOCAL_USER \Software\microsoft\windowsNT\currentversion\appcompatflags\layers folder , and runs well.

When i set the same value in the folder through an application built in VC++ 2010 , it doesn't work why..?

are there any other dependencies , that i should look into..?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the hive is (and has been, ever since the dawn of Windows Registry) named `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

There also is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, you seem to be mixing things up here. I highly doubt your `HK_LOCAL_USER` has ever really worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also, setting the compatibility flag for an application that is still under active development seems like the wrong way to go. Have you  looked into why the application needs that flag? Do you know what code would need to change in order for it to run on Windows 7 without the compatibility fixes? In most cases the changes are quite small.